# Why does app terminate for no reason when I scroll the mouse wheel while the control key is pressed?

Tags: c, winapi

When the control key is down and then I scroll the mouse wheel the app terminates for no reason. I am testing this on Windows XP. It only happens when the control key is pressed while scrolling. If the control key is not pressed while scrolling, it doesn't happen. Don't know how it is with the other operating systems. Use the code below to test this

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hEdit = 0;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        MoveWindow(hEdit, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        SendMessage(hEdit, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof wc;
    wc.hbrBackground = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("MainClass");

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) 
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("Hello"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 40, 20, 400, 200,
        0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if(!hwnd) 
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

If I comment out the 3 lines below, and the control key is pressed while scrolling, it doesn't happen

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    SendMessage(hEdit, msg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```

Comment: You have to give more context. It is not clear what you are trying. Can you e.g. give more source code. What kind of app etc.

Comment: Is it a crash, or just a silent exit? Have you tried running in a debugger? Or use any other kind of tool to monitor messages?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's a silent exit

Comment: At a guess, the `hEdit` window is sending the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message right back to you. Recursive loop -> stack exhaustion.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have a subclassed edit control that I don't want it to receive any mouse input or focus, so it seems like `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` is the only way to simulate wheel scroll. But even without subclassing this happens too

Comment: @Rm32a He's saying that using `SendMessage(hEdit, msg, wParam, lParam);` doesn't make any sense. Your program and the window might keep tossing that hot potato back and forth between them until something breaks. What do you actually intend to do when you get a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`?

Comment: @Lundin I want the edit control to scroll up and down when the mouse wheel is scrolled anywhere when the main window has focus. But I have subclassed the edit control and return 0 on WM_RBUTTONUP, WM_CUT, WM_COPY, WM_PASTE, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, and WM_CONTEXTMENU

Comment: If the control key isn't pressed when the wheel is scrolled, everything works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on what I said in my comment:

1. Your window class forwards `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` to the edit control
2. If the control key is pressed, the edit control ignores the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message and passes it to `DefWindowProc`.
3. `DefWindowProc` passes the message up the parent chain (this behavior is documented in the [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx)).
4. Your window receives the forwarded message and loops back to step #1

Eventually you run out of stack and your process is terminated.

There are three ways you could fix this:

The first (and probably the safest) is to use a flag to prevent the recursive loop; e.g.:

```
static bool fInForwardMsg; // if you have multiple windows you would want to make this a local variable

case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    if (!fInForwardMsg) {
        fInForwardMsg = true;
        SendMessage(hEdit, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        fInForwardMsg = false;
    }
    break;
```

The second solution relies on the fact that the edit control looks at the `wParam` value to see if the control key is down (it also checks for shift as well, incidentally). This is internal undocumented behavior and subject to change, so you shouldn't rely on it, but you should be able to prevent the problem by not forwarding the original value of `wParam`. E.g.:

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    SendMessage(hEdit, msg, wParam & ~0xffff, lParam);
    break;
```

The third solution is also the simplest; since the edit control doesn't actually do anything if shift or control are held down, simply don't forward the message in those cases:

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    if (!(wParam & (MK_SHIFT | MK_CONTROL))
        SendMessage(hEdit, msg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```